# Delete specific characters from a specific line of an INI, and save changes

Tags: string, batch-file, ini

I'm trying to make a batch file that will edit an ini file by removing specific 3 character strings within a specific line of the INI file (in this case the dbside= line). Essentially if any of the following strings:
Djg,Msc,Sbf,Zml,Sbi,Sge,Sgs,Ssb,Sus,Srz,Zhp,Zsq,Zsm,Zrg
are found within the dbside= line, it will remove them and save the new ini file.

So far I have:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

@for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir') do set "StyleDir=%%~b"

@for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir') do set "StyleDir=%%~b"

@for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir') do set "StyleDir=%%~b"
```

basically its asking the registry where the ini file is, then I've tried a few different things to actually modify "%StyleDir%\Style.ini"

Any help is very appreciated

**EDIT**

So, it's been a while since I've been able to get back to this project. So that everyone has it, the first several lines of the ini file are:

```
    [Default]
    DataHome=C:\ProgramData\Zephyr\Data
    SQLiteHome=c:\programdata\zephyr\data
    [DataBaseList]
    DbsId=Mng,Fnd,Set,Stl,Isa,Zac,Djg,Msc,Sbf,Zml,Sbi,Sge,Sgs,Ssb,Sus,Srz,Zhp,Zsq,Zsm,Zrg,Zin,Ecn,Ind,Man
    CustDbSId=Man
    [ZephyrApps]
    SAName=Style.exe
    AAName=Alloc.exe
    SAVersion=8.4.0
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
    [Default]
    DataHome=C:\ProgramData\Zephyr\Data
    SQLiteHome=c:\programdata\zephyr\data
    [DataBaseList]
    DbsId=Mng,Fnd,Set,Stl,Isa,Zac,Zin,Ind,Ecn,Man
    CustDbSId=Man
    [ZephyrApps]
    SAName=Style.exe
    AAName=Alloc.exe
    SAVersion=8.4.0
```

Alternatively, an approach could be to just re-write DbsID= with Mng,Fnd,Set,Stl,Isa,Zac,Zin,Ind,Ecn + whatever is in CustDbsID=

The rough thing I've got so far is:

```
    @echo off
    for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir 2^>nul' ) do set "StyleDir=%%~b"

    for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir 2^>nul') do set "StyleDir=%%~b"

    for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir 2^>nul') do set "StyleDir=%%~b" 2^>nul
    CD %StyleDir%

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr DbsId style.ini') do set DbsId=%%a
    echo=%DbsId%
    pause
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Djg,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Sbf,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Zml,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Sbi,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Sge,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Sgs,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Ssb,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Sus,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Srz,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Zhp,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Zsq,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Zsm,= %
    set string=%DbsId%
        set string=%DbsId:Zrg,= %   
    pause
```

The pauses are in place just to see if I'm doing what I'm supposed to be doing. This is of course before the backup and replacement of the file.

To be honest, I didn't have the best understanding for some of the answers I received, so I'm hoping that this clarifies what I'm trying to do. I'm sorry for not providing a good amount of information before.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")
SET "styledir=c:\106x"
SET "inifile=q27973295.txt"
(
 FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("%styledir%\%inifile%") DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
   IF /i "%%b"=="dbside" (
    SET "line=%%c"
    FOR %%d IN (Djg,Msc,Sbf,Zml,Sbi,Sge,Sgs,Ssb,Sus,Srz,Zhp,Zsq,Zsm,Zrg) DO SET "line=!line:%%d=!"
    ECHO(dbside=!line!
   ) ELSE (
    ECHO(%%a
   )
  )
 )
)>"%tempfile%a"

TYPE "%tempfile%a"
REM move "%tempfile%a" "%styledir%\%inifile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You have already derived the value of 'styledir`- I used a convenient directory and recorded this dummy data (a smaple would have been good...) in a file named`q27973295.txt`

```
junk junk
whatever and so on
dbside=waffle waffle Djg leave Msc hello Sbf 2 Zml 3 Sbi 4 Sge 5 Sgs 6 Ssb 7 Sus 8 Srz 9 Zhp 10 Zsq 11 Zsm 12 Zrg
continue blah blah blah
```

The result in the tempfile generated was:

```
junk junk
whatever and so on
dbside=waffle waffle  leave  hello  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12 
continue blah blah blah
```

Whether you `move /y` the tempfile over your original or `copy /y` it and then delete the tempfile, I'll leave to your discretion. Naturally, **test first**.

Note that `@echo off` turns `echo` off so that there's no need to prefix each line with `@`.

Note also that the deletion of the characters in the target line is case-insensitive.

Comment: I'm not sure your last sentence is clear enough. A reader may think you are talking about deletion of the temp file, when in reality you are referring to the fact that the batch search and replace is case insensitive. This may be a problem for the OP.

Comment: I've added some additional notes if anyone has any further ideas. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave it up to you to establish the location of your INI file.

Performing a case sensitive search and replace is quite difficult (and slow) using pure native batch - not worth the effort.

I would use my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that performs a regular expression search and replace on text. JREPL.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

By "dbside= line" I assume you mean a line that begins with `dbside=`. I'll assume there may be white space before and after the name, such that `dbside  = some value` also counts.

```
call jrepl "Djg|Msc|Sbf|Zml|Sbi|Sge|Sgs|Ssb|Sus|Srz|Zhp|Zsq|Zsm|Zrg" "" /jbegln "skip=($txt.search(/^\w*dbside\w*=/)!=0)" /f "%StyleDir%\Style.ini" /o -
```

The first search and replace arguments are straight-forward. The /JBEGLN option instructs the utility to skip the search/replace if the line is not a "dbside=" line. The /F option specifies the source file, and the /O option with `-` value instructs JREPL to overwrite the original file with the result.

If all searches should be case insensitive, then the following variation works:

```
call jrepl "Djg|Msc|Sbf|Zml|Sbi|Sge|Sgs|Ssb|Sus|Srz|Zhp|Zsq|Zsm|Zrg" "" /jbegln "skip=($txt.search(/^\w*dbside\w*=/i)!=0)" /i /f "%StyleDir%\Style.ini" /o -
```

There is full documentation embedded within JREPL.BAT. The help is accessed by using `JREPL /?`